# ¿Como generar un response de un POST, con Django REST Framework Bulk?

Tags: python, django, rest

Quisiera saber cual es la manera para que el Response de un POST con rest_framework_bulk, sea modificable ya que de manera predeterminado siempre me retorna el mismo objeto o array de objeto que se le envía por el servicio.

modelo:

```
class employee():
    name = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name='name')
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name='profession')
    userCreation = models.ForeignKey(userCreation, verbose_name='user')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='employee'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers:

```
from django.forms import widgets
from .models import employee
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_bulk import (BulkListSerializer, BulkSerializerMixin, ListBulkCreateUpdateDestroyAPIView,)

class employeeSerializer(BulkSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        relation_user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
        model = employee
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'profession', 'relation_user')
```

vista:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import employee
from .serializers import employeeSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework_bulk import ListBulkCreateAPIView

class createEmployee(ListBulkCreateAPIView):
    queryset = employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = employeeSerializer

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(relation_user=self.request.user)
```

url:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from employee import views

urlpatterns = [url(r'^api/createEmployee/$', views.createEmployee.as_view())]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(relation_user=self.request.user)
```

asi funciona muy bien y crea el empleado sin problemas,
Json que envio al servico rest

```
{
    name: 'Jhon',
    profession: 'Medic'
}
```

y esta es la respuesta:

```
{
    name: 'Jhon',
    profession: 'Medic'
}
```

yo quisiera que en el Response se pudiera colocar algo diferente como una suma, un calculo o simplemente un mensaje que diga empleado creado.

creo que con una APIView seria algo como

```
return Response(succes='Empleado creado con exito')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder modificar/personalizar la respuesta de la petición POST es necesario agregar un objeto response y setiar los valores con los atributos de la respuesta que quieres enviar.

Debes modificar tu vista o archivo view.py con lo siguiente:

```
from .serializers import personSerilizer
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class createEmployee(generics.CreateAPIView):

    queryset = employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = employeeSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        self.perform_create(serializer)
        response = {}
        response['success'] = True
        response['message'] = "Registro guardado exitosamente"
        response['status'] = status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        request.data.get('name')}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pides es redundante y rompe la principio [DRY de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry). Lo que pides lo puedes encontrar en la respuesta misma, en el campo `status`, que cuando creas un objeto te devuelve un código, generalmente el `201`. Puedes consultar los códigos de estado en la [documentación](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes/).

Con esta respuesta puedes tomar las medidas que consideres adecuadas.

```
from rest_framework import status


if status == status.HTTP_201_CREATED:
    print('Empleado creado con éxito')
```

Ahora bien, contestando a tu pregunta, puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
from rest_framework import status


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def algo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.status == status.HTTP_201_CREATED:
        return Response({"mensaje": "Empleado creado con éxito", "data": request.data})
    return Response({"message": "Algún mensaje en GET"})
```

Comment: Entiendo tú punto, creo que no me hice entender, yo quisiera que la respuesta fuese algo distinto por ejemplo si al enviar el POST la respuesta sea la cantidad de empleados existentes, utilizando ListBulkCreateAPIView ya que por medio de un @api_view es sencillo, pero con el ListBulkCreateAPIView no lo logro conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no entiendo tu pregunta del todo, estas utilizando un Serilizer para responder

En el django restframework clasico seria

```
class createEmployee(ListBulkCreateAPIView):
    queryset = employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = employeeSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        # Llamamos el metodo create del ApiView y es por es donde se crea el objeto
        result = super(createEmployee, self).create(request)
        return Result({'success': True, 'message': 'Creado correctamente'})
```

O ponerlo directamente en el POST(cosa que no recomiendo por que los restframework decorator routers no funcionarían bien al usar Post), de la documentación de Django restframework tenemos este ejemplo.

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        # return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) 
        return Response({'success': True}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```